# Estimate "potential" from data

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, potential-energy, error-analysis, statistics, data-analysis

I have the following problem:
I am given time-seriesdata, which I am told solves the equation of motion which corresponds to a Lagrangian of the form $L=T-V(x)$.
Is it possible to infer $V(x)$ from the time-series data?
If so how? I don't just want to know $V(x(t))$ i.e. what the potential energy is at different time points. But I want to know $V(x)$.
For example is it possible to reconstruct the $V(x)=\frac{x^2}{2}$ for a harmonic oscillator given time series data of the position?

I thought of doing it by taking the histogram of the data and using the intuition from mechanics that systems tend to stay in low potential regions, but I am not sure if one can use this here.

Comment: This is so vague, that one can not imagine what you want , data " subject to a Lagrangian"  ??

Comment: Well ok. What I mean is I have a processes which I'm told solves the eom corresponding to a Lagrangian of that form. The kinetic energy is straight forward. But is there a way to infer the potential from time series data?

Answer (score 3):

I assume your system is 1-dimensional (since you write the potential as $V(x)$). When you say "time series data" I assume you mean position ($x$) and velocity ($\dot{x}$) as a function of time, sampled with a sampling frequency high enough so that aliasing is absent or negligible. If $\dot{x}$ is unavailable, you can still estimate it by taking the (numerical) derivative of $x$ (by finite differences or any other more sophisticated method).

Let me first assume that noise is absent. Given the $\dot{x}$ time series, you can obviously compute the kinetic energy as a function of time. Now, a key point is that you either have a conservative system (i.e. the Lagrangian is time-independent) or not. In the latter case, I think there is no way to infer $V(x)$ without knowing something more about the system - you definitely need a model to fit your data. In the former case, you can leverage the conservation of energy, so that your kinetic energy $T$ and your potential energy $V(x)$ add up to a time-independent constant $E$. Therefore, you can determine $V(x)$ as $E - T$. Now, you don't know $E$, meaning that **you can determine $V(x)$ only up to a constant**, which is  always true for potential energies (setting the "zero" is always an arbitrary choice).
Therefore, you can simply take $V(x) = -T$.

The presence of noise does not change the general idea, but its practical effects really depend on what kind of noise it is and what is the signal-to-noise ratio (SNR). I will assume that you have a plain old Gaussian white noise and that the SNR is much larger than one. Then, in practice, I would try to filter it out by numerically low-pass filtering the $x$ and $\dot{x}$ data before doing the calculations. Of course, things get much more complicated for SNR close or below 1, or if noise is parametric. Then, again, you need a model of your system.